# startx blank screen

Tags: mate-desktop, troubleshooting, startx

This happened after I changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` and updating the grub config. After rebooting when I do `startx` I only get a black screen with a mouse. If I start a terminal it keeps blinking. I'm on arch with mate and with nvidia . `cat /var/log/Zorg.0.log | grep EE` returns nothing. `journalctl -p4` returns the following:

```
    -- Reboot --
Jun 15 23:40:40 arch-pc mate-session[578]: WARNING: Unable to find provider '' of required component 'dock'
Jun 15 23:40:40 arch-pc wnck-applet[645]: Locale not supported by C library.
                                                  Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Jun 15 23:40:40 arch-pc notification-ar[693]: Locale not supported by C library.
                                                      Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Jun 15 23:40:40 arch-pc clock-applet[695]: Locale not supported by C library.
                                                   Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Jun 15 23:40:41 arch-pc clock-applet[695]: Negative content width -9 (allocation 1, extents 5x5) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
```

What could be the cause of this, and how could it be fixed?

Contents of ~/.xinitrc :

```
  exec mate-session
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `~/.xinitrc`?

Comment: @LucasRamage shared.

Comment: I always look in the `Xorg.0.log` file when I run into problems. It's a fairly descriptive file, and it, as well as the Nvidia driver should tell you what went wrong. Give it a look. If you can't sort it. Post a copy.